# Indent List in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and working with list. I tried using one of the code I saw on w3schools which shows how to indent lists:

```
<html>
<body>

<h4>A nested List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

My css is overriding it so it all apears on the same vertical line.  Is there any CSS code I could use locally on the list to override the main css file? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BoltClock: Based on his questions specification, I think he meant to ask on how to override the main css, locally. In that case his main css is irrelevant, but if its not the case, then yes.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, simply use something like:

```
ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

And it will bump each successive `ul` by 10 pixels.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VU3V5/)

Comment: This code give padding to the first ul as well, so a class should be defined and added to the list which needs indent

Comment: You can just use `ul ul` if you want it from the second level and down.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like some of your styles are being reset.

By default in most browsers, `ul`s and `ol`s have `margin` and `padding` added to them.

You can override this (and many do) by adding a line to your css like so

```
ul, ol {  //THERE MAY BE OTHER ELEMENTS IN THE LIST
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

In this case, you would remove the element from this list or add a `margin`/`padding` back, like so

```
ul{
    margin:1em;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/vbMbQ/1/

Answer (score 11):

I solved the same problem by adding text-indent to the nested list.

```
<h4>A nested List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul id="list2">
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

#list2
{
 text-indent:50px;
}
```

Comment: a better solution would be to avoid using id or class in the markup and do this strictly with css. margin or padding are a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, all lists are being displayed vertically anyways. So do you want to display it horizontally?

Anyways, you asked to override the main css file and set some css locally. You cannot do it inside `<ul>` with `style=""`, that it would apply on the children (`<li>`).

Closest thing to locally manipulating your list would be:

```
<style>
    li {display: inline-block;}
</style>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
        <li>Black tea</li>
        <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I highly doubt he wanted horizontal items seeing as he asks about indenting the lists.

Comment: Same, but its meant as an example on local css. I highly doubt that, he wanted to set padding-left: 10px; too..?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Adjacent sibling combinators] as described in the W3 CSS Selectors Recommendation[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-combinators)
So you can use a `+` sign (or even a `~` tilde) apply a padding to the nested `ul` tag, as you described in your question and you'll get the result you need.
I also think what you want it to override the main css, locally.
You can do this:

```
<style>
    li+ul {padding-left: 20px;}
</style>
```

This way the inner `ul` will be nested including the bullets of the `li` elements.
I wish this was helpful! =)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use html to override the css locally.  I was having a similar issue and this worked for me:

```
<html>
<body>

<h4>A nested List:</h4>
<ul style="PADDING-LEFT: 12px">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text to show left edge of container.<p>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

The above will add 30px of space between the bullet or number and your text.

```css
li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text to show left edge of container.<p>
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

The above will add 30px of space between the bullet or number and the left edge of the container.