# How do I indent to the right an li

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

How do I indent to the right an li in Bootstrap 4? I have this code but the circle bullet of the li is one character to the left of the `<h6>`. I got position static.

```
<h6>Test1</h6>
<li>Test2</li>
```

Comment: Attach a class to li with either margin or padding that depends on what you intend to do and what else you have there.

Comment: That markup is invalid if you have it between `<li>` elements going by what you show. You aren't showing the CSS you are using either so we can't be much help without the complete markup.

Comment: This question already has an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985755/indent-list-in-html-and-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your `li` elements inside a `ul` tag.

```html
<h6>Test1</h6>
  <ul>
    <li>Test2</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not make any sense to locate an `<li>` element right after an `<h>` tag. `<li>` elements are supposed to only be located in a list element such as `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

If you want to have a bold text just left to a `<ul>` list, you need to locate it in another block element (`<div>` for example), which with proper CSS you can locate just left to the `<ul>` list.